# Unity comparing vectors with Vector3 == operator

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, compare, operators

What I'm trying to do here is basically when a player is "moved" it selects a target position, and updateWalkCycle updates the character's position till it is == to the targetPosition. However, the condition never seem to hit true. The API said == and != should account for close values also, so I'm not entirely sure whats wrong.

I've checked the Debug.Log and when the values are ie.)

```
Playerpos: (50.3, 60, 0), 
TargetPos: (50.3, 60, 0), 
difference: (0, 0, 0)
```

the condition still false.

```
void Update()
{
    moveCharacter();
    updateWalkCycle();
}

public void updateWalkCycle()
{
    if ( targetPosition != myTransform.position )
    {
        isMoving = true;

        Vector3 difference = targetPosition - myTransform.position;

        float translation = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        myTransform.position = new Vector3(myTransform.position.x, myTransform.position.y + translation, 0);

        Debug.Log("PlayerPos: " + myTransform.position + " target: " + targetPosition + "diff: " + difference + "bool: " + (targetPosition == myTransform.position));
    }
}

public void moveCharacter()
{
    if (!isMoving)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            targetPosition = new Vector3(myTransform.position.x, myTransform.position.y + 1, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Floating point values that are calculated aren't truncated and they don't show the exact values on Debug.Log. The speed being calculated using Time.DeltaTime makes the values "non-exact", causing the bool to return false.